# C# The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core

I've created a blank NUnit prject, and it doesn't see reference to NUnit, despite of it is in Dependences -> Packages.

```
using NUnit.Framework; # C# The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found


namespace NUnitTestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**NUnitTestProject1.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You'll need to add more detail than that. What framework version is the test project? See those little yellow triangle glyphs on the dependency icon - that means there is something wrong with the reference.

Comment: project is .net core 3.1

Comment: Pfff.. Is working after opening NUnitTestProject1.csproj or some other stuff, I deleted old I created new one identical, nothing more

Comment: I had the same problem with xUnit - restart Visual Studio solves it

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to restore your dependencies:

- RMB on the Solution and select `Restore Nuget packages`

Other things to try if that doesn't work:

- Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders for the test project.
- Restart VS.
- Update the `PackageReference` versions (I can see they are slightly out of date). Just RMB on solution and select `Manage nuget packages` -> Update.